# how to check the operator precedence

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

I want to check the precedence of operator of" *(get the of a pointer) and ++",
how should I design a sentence and then test it?

```
char* s
*s++;
```

this can not test the ++ operator, because it's on the right.

Comment: You can check it by just looking it up online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could "test" by making a mini program and then checking the output.

```
int main() {
    char c[] = "hello";
    char* s = c;
    std::cout << *s++ << std::endl;　// prints 'h'
    std::cout << *s << std::endl;　// prints 'e'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify, but from your example I assume you are referring to the *postfix* operator ++ rather than the *prefix* form. In which case, your expression:

```
*s++;
```

**is** a good test of operator precedence, because it could be interpreted as either:

```
(*s)++;    // -> increment the char pointed at by s
```

or:

```
*(s++);    // -> increment the pointer s itself
```

depending on which operator binds more tightly (has higher precedence).

In fact, the rule in C/C++ is that postfix operators always bind more tightly than prefix operators, so the second interpretation above is the correct one.

To actually **see** which has occurred in your program, you will require some further set up and output - in particular you need to initialize `s` to point to something first.

Please say if you need assistance with this latter part.

Comment: maybe this is wrong. I think may could not check the postfix ++ and *,because the postfix ++ always take effect after "expression is run".

Comment: @user1279988: It's true that the value returned by the postfix ++ operator is the old (unchanged) value, but this doesn't mean that the operator precedence has no effect. You are right that the two different bracketings in my answer have the same value as expressions (they are both equal to simply `*s`), but they differ in their *side effects*. I.e. you will be able to detect a difference in the following lines of the program. The key difference is that ++ is applied to different things in either case - so it's a different object that has been incremented. ...

Comment: @user1279988: For example, you could output both `s` and `*s` before and after to see which has changed.